# How can i remove duplicates from the output of tshark output

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, posix

```
sudo tshark -i ppp0 'tcp port 80   \
and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'   \
-R'http.request.method == "GET" && http.request.uri contains "/ABC/XYZ"' \
-T fields -e http.host -e http.request.uri
```

I am using the above lines of tshark filtering the output based on /ABC/XYZ.
it outputs dynamically random data for example like where i find duplicate lines 
example :

```
1bcdJOSHhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
1bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
1bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
3bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
2bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
1bcdJOSHhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
3bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Is there any way to remove the duplicates without creating any file
may be using some kind of buffer or pipe.

or can tshark itself do it

EDIT : I am not sure why but i get what i want after i prefix tshark with `stdbuf -o L` as suggested by meuh

Comment: @Pandya i am not sure why it does not seem to work

Comment: it doesn't work.I believe it is not exaclty duplicate.Please dont delete

Comment: for that, question should clearly say about facing difficulties while processing (piping) on tshark output. This will not be deleted though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a stop condition on your tshark you can simply pipe the output into `|sort -u`. Alternatively, pipe continuous output into

```
awk '{if(!seen[$0]++)print}'
```

You may need to have tshark not buffer its stdout: try prefixing the tshark with `stdbuf -o L`.

Comment: do you know why stdbuf -o L helps here

Comment: Some programs use the standard library to print data and the library detects if the output is to the terminal or to a file or pipe. If output is to a terminal, each print is output immediately, but if to a file the output is optimised and only written when there is a full buffer. `stdbuf` is a utility to make the standard library never buffer output.